# WiFi Scan library for iOS (without jailbreak)

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

I'm new to iOS programming and currently doing a project for college.

As part of the project I need to be able to use my iPhone to list all available WiFi basestations in the area with respective RSSI values. This is something similar to what can be done by Apple's AirPort Utility for iPhone.

I searched everywhere and there seems to be no straightforward way to do this with normal public libraries. I do not need to publish the app in the App Store, just need to test it with my iPhone. I do not intend to jailbreak it though. Is there a way of me accessing functions to perform a WiFi scan?

This seems to be a solution: http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless. Does anyone know how to get started with it and if it works in non-jailbroken devices?

This appears to be an alternative: https://github.com/ipinak/iOS-WiFi. Again, how would I use it with a non-jailbroken device?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can still do this even without jailbreaking your device, just use the private APIs, you are only restricted if you go through the app store.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the iOS-WiFi project on github, since you're not planning on submitting your app to the app store.  You can use private APIs all you want in development, just not when you want to go to production.